Unable to configure the Datasource realm through embedded tomcat jar.(not an springboot app)
On tomcat 8.x ,We have been using JDBCRealm to set the connection parameter like jdbc url, user name ,password and with these details we initialize the context and start the server .  After upgrading to tomcat 10 i am unable to set the datasource since conncetion url , user name ,password is not present in DatasourceRealm  class. I am aware the we should use javx.sql.datasource and some how bind that to Datasource Realm . Programatically i am unable to get the exact code on how to bind. It would be great help if someone help , Thanks in advance.
This below code basically needs to converted to work in tomcat 10
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;


Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(port);
StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath,        docBase.getAbsolutePath());
JDBCRealm jdbcRealm = new JDBCRealm();
jdbcRealm.setDriverName("org.postgresql.Driver");
jdbcRealm.setConnectionURL(String.format("jdbc:postgresql://****", password));
jdbcRealm.setConnectionName("**********");
jdbcRealm.setConnectionPassword(password);
jdbcRealm.setUserTable("auth_user");
jdbcRealm.setRoleNameCol("role_name");
ctx.setRealm(jdbcRealm);
MessageDigestCredentialHandler credhandler = new MessageDigestCredentialHandler();
credhandler.setAlgorithm("SHA-512");
jdbcRealm.setCredentialHandler(credhandler);
ctx.setRealm(realm);
tomcat.start();

What has been tried and not working:
tomcat.enableNaming();
    ContextResource resourceLink = new ContextResource();
    resourceLink.setProperty("driverClassName", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    resourceLink.setProperty("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cmt");
    resourceLink.setProperty("username", "test");
    resourceLink.setProperty("password", password);
    resourceLink.setType("javax.sql.DataSource");
    resourceLink.setName("jdbc/test");
    resourceLink.setAuth("Container"); resourceLink.setName("jdbc/test");
    context.getNamingResources().addResource(resourceLink);
    DataSourceRealm jdbcRealm = new DataSourceRealm();
    jdbcRealm.setDigest("SHA-512");
    jdbcRealm.setUserTable("auth_user"); 
    jdbcRealm.setUserNameCol("user_name");
    jdbcRealm.setUserCredCol("user_pass");
    jdbcRealm.setUserRoleTable("auth_user_roles");
    jdbcRealm.setRoleNameCol("role_name");
    jdbcRealm.setDataSourceName("jdbc/test");
    ctx.setRealm(realm);

Used this above code to add the data source, but not working. Tomcat is unable to detect the data source and skipping to connect the DB.  Wanted to know the code logic on how to set data source properties to set or bind to Tomcat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext object

Is the code ever executed? May be it's in the wrong place. Check tomcat 8 to tomcat 9 migration since DataSourceRealm was introduced in 9 version
